# Use today's year/month/week as reference in Google query language

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I'm trying to sum a column of data, payments (accounting) relative to the date of receipt in another column. I want to isolate payments made in a given year, month, or week, without having to change anything in the query code.

This is roughly what I'm working with, trying to use either `TODAY()` or `NOW()` in order to have it automatically update:

```
=query(amount,"select sum(H) where year(F) = year(today())")
```

I've also tried doing something similar, while referencing a cell that would read today's year, but have had difficulties with this:

```
=query(amount,"select sum(H) where year(F) = '"&text(R1,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'")
```

where R1 is a cell reading `=YEAR(TODAY))`

If I can get the first formula to work with both year, month, and also week, that'd be perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be done but you will need to add a few more parameters to the query...

```
=SUM(IFERROR(QUERY(A1:B, 
 "select sum(B) 
  where year(A)="&YEAR(TODAY())&"
  group by A 
  label sum(B)''", 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is perfect.  I defer to it.

But as a caution to anyone trying something similar, using the **month(A)** instead of year(A):

The scalar function month() when used in the WHERE clause on a column in a QUERY is actually zero based.  So January is 0 and December is 11.  So add a minus one.

If your results are off by one month, try this:

```
where
 month(A) = " & MONTH(TODAY()) -1 & "
```

Or if you are referencing a date in a cell:

```
where
 year(C) = "& YEAR(C$16) &"
 and month(C) = "& MONTH(C$16) -1 &"
```

**References:**

- [Scalar functions](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#scalar-functions) (mentions the month function as being zero based)

Note: I would have just left this as a comment to the accepted answer above, but I do not have enough "reputation" points to be allowed to comment.